# How can I fix my touchscreen on my Droid 2 Global?

Tags: touchscreen

Anyone know what to do if your phone's touchscreen won't respond. I have tried removing the battery and SIM card, turning it off, letting the battery completely die and then recharge. Is there anything else I could do?

Note: I have never placed my phone near water, so it cannot be due to water damage.

MODEL NUMBER: A956.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you havent flashed other roms, its time to replace the screen.